# How to add a true corner radius to the menu flyout?

Tags: xaml, uwp

Now it looks like this.

[image: Now it looks like this]

I use MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle in MenuFlyout -

```
<MenuFlyout x:Name="MenuFlyout" 
            MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle="{ThemeResource MenuFlyoutAcrilickThemeResources}"
            >
                <MenuFlyoutItem Icon="Paste" Text="Вставить"  Click="MenuFlyoutItemPaste_Click" />
                <MenuFlyoutItem Icon="Copy" Text="Скопировать" Click="MenuFlyoutItemCopy_Click"  />
            </MenuFlyout>
</MenuFlyout>
```

Style code

```
<Style x:Key="MenuFlyoutAcrilickThemeResources" TargetType="MenuFlyoutPresenter">
    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,3" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource MenuFlyoutBackgroundAcrylicBrush}" />
</Style>
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add another `Setter` which affects the default shadow property, like this:

```
<Setter Property="IsDefaultShadowEnabled" Value="False" />
```

Also I recommend using a corner radius of 3, since that's what WinUI 3 uses.

Answer (score 2):

Use IsDefaultShadowEnabled to false.

```
<Button Content="Options">
      <Button.Flyout>
          <MenuFlyout>
              <MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
                  <Style TargetType="MenuFlyoutPresenter">
                      <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="20"/>
                      <Setter Property="IsDefaultShadowEnabled" Value="False"/>
                  </Style>
              </MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
              <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Reset"/>
              <MenuFlyoutSeparator/>
              <ToggleMenuFlyoutItem Text="Repeat" IsChecked="True"/>
              <ToggleMenuFlyoutItem Text="Shuffle" IsChecked="True"/>
          </MenuFlyout>
      </Button.Flyout>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another `Setter` to modify the background property:

```xml
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
```

However, depending on your SDK verison, [Microsoft recommends a different approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.menuflyoutpresenter#remarks):

> Starting in Windows 10, version 1607 (SDK 14393), generic.xaml includes resources that you can use to modify the colors of a control in different visual states without modifying the control template. In apps that target this software development kit (SDK) or later, modifying these resources is preferred to setting properties such as Background and Foreground. For more info, see the Light-weight styling section of the Styling controls article.

Comment: i'm now use background in this style. 
It does not affect in any way

Comment: I got the opinion that for background it has another background layer

Comment: @RomanSERAZUM It's relative. If the outside background is white, you will not see the four white corners.